# Allow the consumer of a polymer element to supply a template

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am creating a polymer element that displays a list of other polymer elements. I would like the consumer of the element to be able to drop the list element on their page and supply the template to be used in the list item element. If they do not supply a template I want to use a default template.

I have tried to accomplish this by binding to the ref attribute of the template. This seems to work if I supply a custom template but not if I do not supply it.

Non working example: http://jsbin.com/futiti/7/edit?html,output

The list item element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-item" attributes="item itemTemplate">
  <template>
    <template bind="{{item}}" ref="{{itemTemplate}}">
    </template>

    <template id="_itemTemplate">
      <li>Default template: {{name}}</li>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      itemTemplate: '_itemTemplate',
      created: function() {
        this.item = {};
      }
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The list element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-list" attributes="drag name list itemTemplate">
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{i in list}}">
      <my-item item="{{i}}" itemTemplate="{{itemTemplate}}"></my-item>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        this.list = [{name: 'Item 1', id: 'item1'},
                     {name: 'Item 2', id: 'item2'},
                     {name: 'Item 3', id: 'item3'}];
      }
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

All I had to do was define the default template before the template that binds to it with ref:
http://jsbin.com/futiti/10/edit?html,output

Comment: Except that this seems to only work when the templates are defined in the same file.